# How to add custom font using @fontface to Storybook? (Need updated answer for storybook version 6.5.5)?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, storybook, nextjs-storybook

I have tried all the solutions available online to add custom font in the Storybook but failed.
Following are the files under .storybook folder that I have added as per this [solution](https://mushti-dev.medium.com/hey-e6faa20b910a):

1. webpack.config.js :

```html
const path = require('path');

module.exports = async ({ config }) => {
  // fonts
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  });

  return config;
};
```

2. preview.head.html

```html
<style type="text/css">
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Eina';
    src: url('../src/styles/Eina03-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Eina';
    src: url('../src/styles/Eina03-SemiBold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Eina';
    src: url('../src/styles/Eina03-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
  }
</style>
```

3. main.js

```html
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  staticDirs: ['../public', '../public/fonts'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-postcss',
      options: {
        postcssLoaderOptions: {
          implementation: require('postcss'),
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  framework: '@storybook/react',
  core: {
    builder: 'webpack5',
  },
  webpackFinal: async config => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

The font is stored in src/styles/.
Also, I already have main.js file so I ignored the config.js, which needed to be added as per the [solution](https://mushti-dev.medium.com/hey-e6faa20b910a)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had issues using the file-loader based approach as well. Here's how I got it working:

**Folder structure**

```
├── .storybook/
│   ├── main.js
│   └── preview-head.html
└── src/
    └── assets/
        └── fonts/
            └── custom-font.otf
```

**preview-head.html**

```html
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'custom-font';
        src: url('fonts/custom-font.otf');
    }
</style>
```

**main.js**

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  stories: [...],
  addons: [...],
  staticDirs: ['../src/assets'],
  framework: '@storybook/react',
};
```

The key here is `staticDirs`. You'll be able to reference all your assets relatively from what you've defined there.

To answer your case more directly, you need to update your `staticDirs` to include `src/styles` and reference your fonts in the @font-face src by `url('Eina03-Regular.ttf')`